# Continuous deployment of IIS settings with MSDeploy

Tags: iis-7, msdeploy, continuous-deployment

We practice continuous deployment with TFS (2008) and are looking for a nice way to handle IIS settings changes. MSDeploy seems like it should be the way to handle this, but after much reading and searching, I haven't found a good answer.

The problem with MSDeploy, as I see it, is that you need to create a deployment package using an existing IIS website. I would like to be able to have the appropriate IIS configuration for the website in source control and have the build create the package.

The only way I can see to do this is to hand craft the archive.xml file. Is my thinking correct or is there a better way?

Comment: If you practice continuous deployment I would assume you test your web site just before you deploy. This would mean that you already have a web site for testing. Using MSDeploy then is no issue. This is the setup I've been using for many months now with multiple daily releases. Maybe I'm overlooking something but I don't see the problem...

Comment: @John - So where do you make IIS changes? Your test website? How do developers pick up these changes? Granted IIS settings typically don't change much, but source control should be the central place for all application specific changes.

Comment: What kind of changes do you mean? For example are these changes in the web.config or in the IIS configuration (e.g. using a different application pool). If it is the latter, I can see your point.

Comment: Yes, it's the latter. My guess is most (windows) teams aren't doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using powershell web administration module (with PSake for the build) to do this. I would still prefer to do this in a declarative manner.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to put a bunch of the website settings into my web.config so that they are in source control and easily deploy-able. Not all though. Some seem to get set higher up in the IIS hierarchy and then cannot be overridden by my web.config.

I've never found a way to do this with application pool settings.

For setting up new sites I wrote a small C# WinForms app that uses the programmatic interface to IIS to create the sites and app pools and change their settings. Probably similar to your PowerShell script.